# binary search not returning the index

Tags: c++

this is my c++ program for binary search and for some reason it is not returning the index of the element that I searched

```
#include <iostream>
//using  namespace std;

struct array {

    int A[10];
    int size;
    int length;
};


void displayArray(struct array arr) {
    std::cout << "the elements are :-" << std:: endl << '\t';
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        std::cout << arr.A[i] << ',';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
}

int binarySearch(struct array arr, int element) {

    int l, h;
    l = 0;
    h = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; l <= h; i++) {
   
        int mid = (l + h) / 2;
        
        if (arr.A[mid] == element)
            return mid;
        else if (arr.A[mid] < element)
            h = mid -1;
        else
            l = mid+1;
        std::cout << mid << std::endl;
    }
    return -1;

}
int main()
{
    struct array arr = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, 10, 7};
    int* p;
    displayArray(arr);
    std::cout << binarySearch(arr, 6) << std::endl;
    
}
```

I tried everything and still, it is not working for some reason
am I missing something here?

Comment: Your `else if` body is not correct, In fact you should swap the statements of `else if` and `else`. Also the condition of `for` is wrong

Comment: You also have fencepost errors. Be careful with indices. Unrelated, but “size” and “length” mean the same thing, semantically. You ought to call “size” something like ”capacity”.

Comment: This program is small enough that you can step through it line by line in the debugger. At each line, inspect the variables and values being tested and assigned. At some point, the program will behave in a manner you did not expect. That is where the problem is. (This assumes of course that you know what to expect.)

Answer (score 1):

change position of l, h. you need to growth mid value if you find bigger value, the other way around, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using  namespace std;

struct array1 {

    int A[10];
    int size;
    int length;
};


void displayArray(struct array1 arr) {
    std::cout << "the elements are :-" << std::endl << '\t';
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        std::cout << arr.A[i] << ',';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}

void binarySearch(struct array1 arr, int element) {

    int l, h;
    l = 0;
    h = arr.length;
    int mid = arr.length / 2;
   

    if (arr.A[mid] == element)
        cout << "i am on index number=" << mid;
    else if ( element< arr.A[mid])
        for (int i = 0; 1; i++)
        {
            if (arr.A[i] == element)
            {
                cout << "i am on index number=" << i;
                break;
            }
        }
    else
        for (int i = mid; 1; i++)
        {
            if (arr.A[i] == element)
            {
                cout << "i am on index number=" << i;
                break;
            }
        }


   
    

  

}

int main()
{
    struct array1 arr = { {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, 10, 7 };
  
    displayArray(arr);
    binarySearch(arr, 6);
    return 0;
```

Comment: used visual studio code and you were getting problem in if else statements. Also try to proper implement binary searching first before structuring the OOP concepts

Comment: Um, this is not a binary search. Its running time is O(n), not O(log n). It also crashes if the element is not present at all.